# How can I check what level of color support a terminal has in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, my goal is to figure out what amount of color support a system has.
What I mean by this is create a function `supportsColor()` that checks how
many colors can be displayed in `sys.stdout`, returning 0 for no color,
1 for 16 different colors support, 2 for 256 different colors support, and 3 for Truecolor (basically any colors).

An example (js package) of how it should work is this: https://github.com/chalk/supports-color

Comment: Have you looked at how that JS works? It has lots of checks for different operating systems, terminal emulators, etc. There's no generic way to do this, it just knows what every terminal application supports.

Comment: Related; [How to detect if the console does support ANSI escape codes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7445658/11082165)

Comment: A very rough approximation can be gotten with the `TERM` environment variable. On my terminal right now, I see `xterm-256color`.